# How to get data from d3js polyline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I would like to create simple shape drawing. When I click the shape it should create a new one. For example, if I click at the top of the triangle I want the new one to appear at the top of current one, if I click on the right side, the new one appears on the right side etc. I am new to d3js so I am struggling how can I get data of the polyline on which I am clicking? For now, I managed to create a function which should do it for me and it does if I manually set new coordinates of the polyline. It creates shapes but I can't get data to manipulate it in order to draw another one. Also, It would be nice if anyone suggested how can I manage different drawing(when clicked top, draw at the top etc...). 
[image: What I have]

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <body>

    <svg width="1000" height="667"></svg>

    <script>
    scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([-10,10])
      .range([75,125]),

    scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([-10,10])
      .range([187.5,125]);

    var o = [];
    poly = [{"x":30, "y":15},
        {"x":40,"y":35},
        {"x":50,"y":15}];

    poly2 = [{"x":50, "y":15},
        {"x":60,"y":35},
        {"x":70,"y":15}];

    poly3 = [{"x":60, "y":35},
        {"x":70,"y":15},
        {"x":90,"y":35}];


    var tab = [];
    cir = [{"x": 50,"y":15,"r": 5}];

    o.push(poly);
    o.push(poly2);
    tab.push(cir);

    function draw()
    {
        var cords = [0, 0]
        d3.select("svg")
            .selectAll("polyline")
            .data(o)
            .enter().append("polyline")
            .attr("points",function(d) { 
                return d.map(function(d) { return [scaleX(d.x),scaleY(d.y)].join(","); }).join(" ");})
            .attr("stroke","black")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) { d3.select(this).style("fill", "red") })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) { d3.select(this).style("fill", "black") })
            .on("click", function(d)
            {
                appendTriangle(d);}
            )
            .attr("stroke-width",2);

    }
    function appendTriangle(triangle)
    {


        var newTriangle = [{x:triangle.x,y:triangle.y},
        {x:triangle.x,y:triangle.y},
        {x:triangle.x,y:triangle.y}];


        o.push(newTriangle);
        draw();
    }
    function appendTriangle2()
    {
        var newTriangle = [{"x":60, "y":35},
        {"x":70,"y":15},
        {"x":90,"y":35},];

        o.push(newTriangle);
        draw();
    }

    draw();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datum (`d`, called `triangle` in the `appendTriangle` function) is an **array** of objects, not an object.

Therefore, you should use the indices, like this:

```
var newTriangle = [{
    x: triangle[0].x,
    y: triangle[0].y
}, {
    x: triangle[1].x,
    y: triangle[1].y
}, {
    x: triangle[2].x,
    y: triangle[2].y
}];
```

Of course, you can do it programmatically:

```
var newTriangle = [];
triangle.forEach(function(d) {
    newTriangle.push({
        x: d.x,
        y: d.y
    })
});
```

Here is a demo showing it (I'm moving the polygon 20 pixels, so the new one doesn't fall over the previous one):

```js
scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([-10, 10])
  .range([75, 125]),

  scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([-10, 10])
  .range([187.5, 125]);

var o = [];
poly = [{
  "x": 30,
  "y": 15
}, {
  "x": 40,
  "y": 35
}, {
  "x": 50,
  "y": 15
}];

poly2 = [{
  "x": 50,
  "y": 15
}, {
  "x": 60,
  "y": 35
}, {
  "x": 70,
  "y": 15
}];

poly3 = [{
  "x": 60,
  "y": 35
}, {
  "x": 70,
  "y": 15
}, {
  "x": 90,
  "y": 35
}];


var tab = [];
cir = [{
  "x": 50,
  "y": 15,
  "r": 5
}];

o.push(poly);
o.push(poly2);
tab.push(cir);

function draw() {
  var cords = [0, 0]
  d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("polyline")
    .data(o)
    .enter().append("polyline")
    .attr("points", function(d) {
      return d.map(function(d) {
        return [scaleX(d.x), scaleY(d.y)].join(",");
      }).join(" ");
    })
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "red")
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "black")
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      appendTriangle(d);
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);

}

function appendTriangle(triangle) {

  var newTriangle = [];
  triangle.forEach(function(d) {
    newTriangle.push({
      x: d.x + 20,
      y: d.y - 20
    })
  });

  o.push(newTriangle);
  draw();
}

function appendTriangle2() {
  var newTriangle = [{
    "x": 60,
    "y": 35
  }, {
    "x": 70,
    "y": 15
  }, {
    "x": 90,
    "y": 35
  }, ];

  o.push(newTriangle);
  draw();
}

draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1000" height="667"></svg>
```

PS: Please have in mind that I'm answering only **one** of your questions, which is the main one, *"How to get data from d3js polyline?"*. Regarding the position of the new element, please ask *another* question: asking about multiple issues in the same question is *too broad* here at StackOverflow.